# How does chrome://webrtc-internals/ come to know that a new tab has opened from which it can gather statistics of an on going webrtc call

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, simplewebrtc

How does chrome://webrtc-internals/ come to know that a new tab is opened and there is an active webrtc call from which it has to gather the statistics.I am more interested in knowing how does it dynamically come to know that this is the tab on which there is an active webrtc call and it needs to start gathering the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

All RTCPeerConnection's in chrome report to the [peer_connection_tracker](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/peerconnection/peer_connection_tracker.h) which in turn sends a message to (the "backend" of) webrtc-internals

Comment: is there a way we can access this by creating an object of RTCPeerConnection or some other means. i am trying to get stats of an existing established webrtc call

Comment: in javascript? The approach described in https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-externals/ should still work.

Comment: what i am trying to do is use getStats() API on the webrtc call which is already established. So how can i get an object of RTCPeerConnection on which i can call getStats() API and get some stats. or is there any other way to achieve this